# Unpacking TCP-fragment give incorrect result

Tags: python, tcp, packet-sniffers, unpack

I have a problem with my packet sniffer. The destination port and source port seems to be wrong in my sniffer. In wireshark the ports is totally different from my sniffers. No result contains port 443 expected from TLS. (The whole tcp-fragment might be wrong.)

Does it have to do something to do with the router?
I also know that there is some problems doing sniffing in windows. Or is my unpacking code just wrong? Am i missing some offset between ip-header and tcp-fragment ?

Socket code: https://pastebin.com/tMuHgz0R

Unpacking code: https://pastebin.com/9ZVfYNEE (full code)

```
  # Unpack tcp fragment
    def tcp_fragment(raw_data):
        tcp_header = struct.unpack('!HHLLBBHHH', raw_data[:20])
        source_port = tcp_header[0]
        destionation_port = tcp_header[1]
        sequence_number = tcp_header[2]
        acknowledgement_number = tcp_header[3]
        offset = tcp_header[4] >> 4
        reserved = tcp_header[4] & 0xF
        flags = get_tcp_flags(tcp_header[5])
        window = tcp_header[6]
        checksum = tcp_header[7]
        pointer = tcp_header[8]

        return {
            TCP_SOURCE_PORT: source_port,
            TCP_DESTINATION_PORT: destionation_port,
            TCP_SEQUENCE_NUMBER: sequence_number,
            TCP_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_NUMBER: acknowledgement_number,
            TCP_OFFSET: offset,
            TCP_RESERVED: reserved,
            TCP_FLAGS: flags,
            TCP_WINDOW: window,
            TCP_CHECKSUM: checksum,
            TCP_POINTER: pointer,
            TCP_PAYLOAD_DATA: raw_data[20:]
        }
```

TCP header result: https://pastebin.com/7xhaEGer

Wireshark result for same packets:
[image: wshark]

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i managed to solve it. It was a quite stupid error. I forgot to account for the ip-header bits when unpacking tcp.

Fixed code would look something like this:

```
# Unpack tcp & ip
def ip_tcp(raw_data):
    iph = ip_header(raw_data)
    iph_length = iph[IP_IHL] * 4

    tcp = tcp_fragment(raw_data, iph_length)

    return (iph, tcp)


# Unpack tcp fragment
def tcp_fragment(raw_data, iph_length):
    tcp_header = struct.unpack('!HHLLBBHHH', raw_data[iph_length:iph_length + 20])
    source_port = tcp_header[0]
    destionation_port = tcp_header[1]
    sequence_number = tcp_header[2]
    acknowledgement_number = tcp_header[3]
    offset = tcp_header[4] >> 4
    reserved = tcp_header[4] & 0xF
    flags = get_tcp_flags(tcp_header[5])
    window = tcp_header[6]
    checksum = tcp_header[7]
    pointer = tcp_header[8]

    return {
        TCP_SOURCE_PORT: source_port,
        TCP_DESTINATION_PORT: destionation_port,
        TCP_SEQUENCE_NUMBER: sequence_number,
        TCP_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_NUMBER: acknowledgement_number,
        TCP_OFFSET: offset,
        TCP_RESERVED: reserved,
        TCP_FLAGS: flags,
        TCP_WINDOW: window,
        TCP_CHECKSUM: checksum,
        TCP_POINTER: pointer,
        TCP_PAYLOAD_DATA: raw_data[iph_length + 20:]
    }
```